# C# List all files with filename under an amazon S3 folder

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Using C# and amazon .Net SDK, able to list all the files with in a amazon S3 folder as below:

```
ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest();           
request.BucketName = _bucketName; //Amazon Bucket Name
request.Prefix = _sourceKey; //Amazon S3 Folder path           
do
{
    ListObjectsResponse response = _client.ListObjects(request);//_client - AmazonS3Client
```

**Output**

```
Folder
Folder/file1.pdf
Folder/file2.pdf
Folder/file3.pdf
```

But i wanted to achieve something like this:

**Desired Output**

```
file1.pdf
file2.pdf
file3.pdf
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 32):

Also you can use the following c# code to retrieve the files information.

```
var bucketName = "your bucket";
var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client("your access key", "your secret key");
var dir = new S3DirectoryInfo(s3Client, bucketName, "your AmazonS3 folder name");
foreach (IS3FileSystemInfo file in dir.GetFileSystemInfos())
{
    Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(file.Extension);
    Console.WriteLine(file.LastWriteTime);
}
```

I am using amazon AWSSDK.Core and AWSSDK.S3 version 3.1.0.0 for .net 3.5. I hope it can help you

Comment: S3DirectoryInfo is under the Amazon.S3.IO namespace.

Comment: Namespace Amazon.S3.IO is not supported on .NET Core.

Comment: This code is also returning Folder/Directory. But I need only files from specific folder.Is there any way to get files only (excluding Folder) ?

Comment: This returns nothing for me.

Answer (score 16):

```
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(S3_ACCESS_KEY, S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, S3_REGIAO);
var lista = s3Client.ListObjectsAsync(S3_BUCKET, $"{S3_SUBDIRETORIO}/{produto}/{produto}.").Result;
var files = lista.S3Objects.Select(x => x.Key);
var arquivos = files.Select(x => Path.GetFileName(x)).ToList();
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read  about giving a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering)

Comment: if we have 45k odd files, then this approach is giving only 1K file only.

Comment: @VineetAgarwal Using the AWS SDK, you can only pull 1000 objects at a time anyway.

Answer (score 10):

**Let's make it clear, simple, and with a little description.**
As we all know, in S3 there is no concept of directories (folders). Ah, what?
So everything inside S3 is nothing but objects.
Let's consider the below example s3 bucket - the bucket name is **testBucket**, the directory name is **testDirectory** and the directory contains two files **testImage.jpg** and **testUserData.txt**.

- testBucket

  - testDirectory

    - testImage.jpg
    - testUserData.txt

```
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client();
string bucketName = "testBucket";
// to list out all the elements inside of a director [To know more][1]
string prefix = "testDirectory/";

ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest
                {
                    BucketName = bucketName,
                    Prefix = prefix,
                    // Use this to exclude your directory name
                    StartAfter = prefix,
                };
ListObjectsResponse response =  s3Client.ListObjects(request);

foreach (S3Object itemsInsideDirectory in response .S3Objects)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(itemsInsideDirectory.Key);
                }
```

**output:**
***If you use 'StartAfter', then output will be***
testDirectory/testImage.jpg
testDirectory/testUserData.txt*

***If you donot use 'StartAfter', then output will be***
*testDirectory/

testDirectory/testImage.jpg

testDirectory/testUserData.txt*

Comment: I think those commands were updated :ListObjectsV2Request and ListObjectsV2Async are new names

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will check  and update it accordingly

Answer (score 8):

```
    AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client();
    ListObjectsRequest listRequest = new ListObjectsRequest
    {
        BucketName = "your-bucket-name",
        Prefix = "example/path"
    };

    ListObjectsResponse listResponse;
    do
    {
        listResponse = client.ListObjects(listRequest);
        foreach (S3Object obj in listResponse.S3Objects)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(obj.Key);
            Console.WriteLine(" Size - " + obj.Size);
        }

        listRequest.Marker = listResponse.NextMarker;
    } while (listResponse.IsTruncated);
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_S3_AmazonS3_ListObjects.htm

Answer (score 2):

```
string bucketName = your bucket name;
S3DirectoryInfo dir = new S3DirectoryInfo(client, bucketName, "folder name");
foreach (IS3FileSystemInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
{
    Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(file.Extension);
    Console.WriteLine(file.LastWriteTime);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When there are large number of objects you may need to use ListObjectsV2Request to read the objects in batches, similar to shown below

```cs
    private readonly IAmazonS3 _amazonS3; // Make sure you initialize this

    public async IAsyncEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> ListObjects(string bucketName, string prefix)
    {
        ListObjectsV2Request objectsV2Request = new ListObjectsV2Request
        {
            BucketName = bucketName,
            Prefix = prefix
        };
        ListObjectsV2Response listObjectsV2Response;
        do
        {
            listObjectsV2Response = await _amazonS3.ListObjectsV2Async(objectsV2Request);
            objectsV2Request.ContinuationToken = listObjectsV2Response.NextContinuationToken;
            yield return listObjectsV2Response.S3Objects.Select(s => s.Key);
        } while (listObjectsV2Response.IsTruncated);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_client = new AmazonS3Client(_awsAccessKeyId, _awsSecretAccessKey, _regionEndpoint);
var req = new ListObjectsV2Request
{
                BucketName = _bucketName,
                Prefix = "upper_folder_name/" + 
                "lower_folder_name/",
                MaxKeys = 100,
                Delimiter = "/",
                FetchOwner = false
            };
            var response = await _client.ListObjectsV2Async(req);
            foreach (var s3Object in response.S3Objects)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s3Object.Key);
            }
 }
```